# URL for Amazon S3 bucket prefix with othername

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

S3 buckets my url where i am uploading file abcd-ss.s3.amazonaws.com//
    but where i want to upload it s3.amazonaws.com//

```
that should not prefix with abcd-ss.

So i hereby cant understand from where it is coming (abcd-ss.) how to remove it can you suggest me?
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use s3.amazonaws.com as your bucket URL? It's not possible.

If you want to use a different name for your bucket URL, this could be implemented

You need to follow these steps:

1. Regsiter new domain in Route53 or migrate your existing one.
   More information here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/registrar.html
2. After you registerd your domain, for exmple mydomain.com, create an S3 bucket with exactly the same name and enable static website hosting on it.
3. After that, you will be able to point your Route53 bomain to your bucket and have a user-friendly URL. More information here:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html

Comment: Hi mukhin, 

Actually from this s3.amazonaws.com we are uploading through backend process similarly for frontend we are using abcd-ss.s3.amazonaws.com but somewhere we need to sync

Comment: I would like to know does it (abcd-ss) been  set in amazon console because i could not find it any code so i am assuming it is set on registering amazon